How to make post request to firestore cloud with custom id?
I am using Firebase cloud REST API with redux toolkit query, I want to ask if I can create a new doc with a custom ID.
The following code works, but firebase generates an auto-id.
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl:
    "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[project-id]/databases/(default)/documents",
});
const userApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQuery,
  reducerPath: "users",

  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    createUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (userInfo: RegisterUser) => ({
        url: `/users`,
        method: "POST",
        body: {
          fields: {
            email: { stringValue: userInfo.email },
            fullname: { stringValue: userInfo.fullname },
            trips: {
              arrayValue: [],
            },
          },
        },

      }),
    }),

But what if I want a custom ID that I send with the request?
I tried the following code by adding the id to the URL:
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl:
    "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[project-id]/databases/(default)/documents",
});
const userApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQuery,
  reducerPath: "users",

  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    createUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (userInfo: RegisterUser) => ({
       url: `/users/${userInfo.id}` //added the id here,

        method: "POST",
        body: {
          fields: {
            email: { stringValue: userInfo.email },
            fullname: { stringValue: userInfo.fullname },
            trips: {
              arrayValue: [],
            },
          },
        },

      }),
    }),

And I got the following error :
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Document \"projects/[project-id/databases/(default)/documents/users/randomId\" not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}


When you define a URL like below:
url: `/users`

It means that you tell Firestore to add a document to the "users" collection using a random document ID. This is happening because you aren't specifying any document ID in the addition operation at all.

But what if I want a custom ID that I send with the request?

To solve this, please note that the Firestore REST API allows you to create a document with a custom ID, if you specify the full document reference in the URL. So, instead of sending a request to the "users" collection, you can include the custom document ID directly in the URL:
So assuming you have a user object, to write the data using the corresponding uid, please use:
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl:
    "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[project-id]/databases/(default)/documents",
});
const userApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQuery,
  reducerPath: "users",

  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    createUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (userInfo: RegisterUser) => ({
        url: `/users/${user.uid}`,  // Custom document ID.
        method: "POST",
        body: {
          fields: {
            email: { stringValue: userInfo.email },
            fullname: { stringValue: userInfo.fullname },
            trips: {
              arrayValue: [],
            },
          },
        },

      }),
    }),

So if you include a custom document ID in the URL, you tell Firestore to create a document with that specific ID instead of generating a random one.

Hello Alex, thank you for your response,
I tired this and got an error :
{
"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Document "projects/pathwise/databases/(default)/documents/users/randomId" not found.",
"status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
}

Can you please edit your question and show me the changed code?

I edited it, the new code with the error !

So there is some randomId document that is already present in the collection? What is the value of userInfo.id? Have you also tried to use PUT instead of POST?

No, there is no document with this ID, I tried to use PUT and got the same error with this error :
'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This error about CORS is unrelated to creating the document. It could be a separate issue related to how your frontend interacts with the backend server. So in my opinion the initial issue looks like it's been solved.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
